Trying to transfer SPL token but keep getting TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError
` Not generating a new wallet as I already have one with public and private keys
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'), 'confirmed');

    const fromWallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
        Uint8Array.from([
            139, 207, 19, 220, 129,....
        ])
    );


    const toWallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
        Uint8Array.from([
            139, 207, 19, 220, 129, 105,....
        ])
    );

    const mintPubkey = new PublicKey("3VTXWW.....");
//checking the values but this has nothing to do
    let mint = await getMint(connection, mintPubkey);
    console.log(mint)

    const fromTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        connection,
        fromWallet,
        mintPubkey,
        fromWallet.publicKey
    );

    const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(connection, fromWallet, mintPubkey, toWallet.publicKey);

    signature = await transfer(
        connection,
        fromWallet,
        fromTokenAccount.address,
        toTokenAccount.address,
        fromWallet.publicKey,
        50
    );

This works well on devnet but mainnet gives the errors
Any help would be appreciated
